# What is the differences in these different PowerShells?

Tags: powershell, prompt

When I install some programs such as Anaconda for Jupyter Notebook and VS Code, I can find additional prompt with those programs.

For Anaconda, there is some bundled app Anaconda Prompt and for VS Code, inside the program there is small prompt windows.

What is differences on them? And why we just don't use Windows basic prompt CMD or PowerShell?

Comment: There is only WinPS 5x (Windows only - closed-sourced and requires full .Net) and below and PSCore v6 and higher (cross-platform open-sourced and requires .Net Core).  All-in-all, PS is PS and only where either can be used and the feature set is different and performance. PS shells are just where you run PS code. PS shells are not PS. Anyone can write there on PS shell. If another dev/scripting tool is calling PS, they will be calling either WinPS or PSCore, whatever version of those you have on your system. Tools can force a PS version as can a PS script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may misunderstand something fundamental about these applications.

Anaconda is a version of the Perl and R languages and it can drop instructions to open a terminal window and call itself.

VS Code is a code editor with an embedded terminal that can be used to run just about any shell, including Anaconda, as desired.

You CAN call the executables for Anaconda from a window opened with CMD, or PowerShell. You can call PowerShell from a CMD window. You can run just about any shell or command interpreter installed in Windows from any terminal window you have opened.

But, to circle back to your question: Anaconda and VS Code are not just two different programs: they are two different TYPES of programs, and have their various features for reasons specific to their distinct purposes.